# Capybara with cucumber giving false positive

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I have these test steps. app_host is pointing to "google.com".

```
  Given /^I am on google\.com$/ do
      visit("/")
  end

  Then /^I should see something$/ do
      has_css?('a#something')
  end
```

Regardless of what I have in the 2nd step, test is passing. I am just wondering if I am missing something here.

Comment: Found the answer. Need to have 'rspec/expectations' and assertion should be something like this has_css?('a#something').should be_true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cucumber steps will only fail if an assertion fails. They do not fail based on if the last line is true or false.

To use `has_css?` in an assertion you can do one of the following:

```
#If you are using RSpec assertions
page.should have_css('a#something')

#If you are using Test::Unit assertions
assert page.has_css?('a#something')
```

Comment: That's right. Found the answer to my question in the docs after I posted. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Definitions